# Files in document library not opening in explorer

Tags: 2007, document-library, explorer

When trying to access a file in a document library folder in explorer, some users are getting the following error:

[image: file not found]

However, this is not the case for all users. The users can though open the files directly from the SharePoint site, just not in explorer. As far as I can see, all permissions are the same for people that can and cannot access the file(s). You can see that the address begins with `\\plcsharepoint` whereas the file is located within `http://plcsharepoint`. I don't know why this is happening but maybe someone could help out?

EDIT: Just to clarify, this issue is in Windows Explorer, not the Explorer View. I.e. What you get when you click Actions > Open with Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

- Is their WebClient running on their machine?

> Start -> Run -> services.msc -> WebClient -> RightClick -> Start

- Also, is the Sharepoint site added to their trusted sites or in the local intranet zone in Internet Explorer?

> IE -> Tools -> Internet Options -> Security -> Reset all zones to
>   default level.

Answer (score 0):

even i have faced this issue earlier....my conclusion was..it works for user when they are accessing the url from the server and gives error [or sometimes open the explorer window and does not display any items in it] to tuser accessing the url from remote machine

Comment: Perhaps in order to mitigate this problem you could create a policy which inserts an entry into the host file / DNS resolving the plcsharepoint to an ip (which is reachable)?

Answer (score 0):

I think relinking the documents present in the doc library may solve your issue. I had the same issue with infopath form library and relinking helped me out.

Comment: No relinking did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, it will explain a bit about explorer view

http://blogs.technet.com/b/manjesh/archive/2010/01/03/all-about-explorer-view-in-sharepoint.aspx

The perons getting the UNC format \ addresses are using WebDAV the others might be using FPRPC.

Comment: It's not explorer view, it is the actual Windows Explorer. I.e. What you get when you go Actions > Open with Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I joined an organization; they gave me a Windows ID to login to the network and a Site Collection ID. Whenever I login with the Site Collection ID on a SharePoint site and click on Actions- Open with explorer i would get a blank windows with no files whereas there were tonnes of files in that document library.

I couldn't understand it in the begining, then I gave access to my Windows ID on that particular Document Library and clicked on open with Windows explorer, now I could see all the files. Strange right! Try it, maybee it will help